# Appending and removing data from html dynamic created table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Not able to remove the dynamic data which i populated on button click to the html table. I want to update these table data again and again on the basis of the variable which contain the data to be displayed.

```js
$("#go").click(function() {
  
    $("#orderGraph").show();
    $("#profitGraph").show();
    $("#report").show();

    $("#go").on('click',function(){
        $("#datatable").remove();
    });

    response = $.parseJSON(response);

    $(function () {
        $.each(response, function (i, item) {
            $('<tr>').append(
            $('<td>').text(item.orderId),
            $('<td>').text(item.purchaseId),
            $('<td>').text(item.shipmentId),
            $('<td>').text(item.useCase),
            $('<td>').text(item.orderCondition),
            $('<td>').text(item.orderType)).appendTo('#datatable');
        }); 
    });
 

    $("#datatable tbody tr").hide();
    $("#datatable tr:contains("+multicompanyUseCaseData+")").show();

});
```

```html
<button id="go" type="submit" value="Submit" >Go</button>

                 <div class="x_content">
                    <table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                      <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Order Id</th>
        <th>Shipment Id</th>
        <th>Purchase Id</th>
  <th>Use Case</th>
  <th>Order Condition</th>
  <th>Order Type</th>
    </tr>
                      </thead>


                      <tbody>

                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
```

Comment: {
  "message": "SyntaxError: missing } after function body",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 36,
  "colno": 67
}

Comment: Post the `html` too buddy..

Comment: `$(function () { ... });` is a short-cut for jQuery's `document.ready` function. It appears that this is *inside* your click handler. I hope `response` is defined somewhere else...

Comment: If I understand this correctly, once you click `#datatable` it's grand-parent gets removed, which will also remove `#datatable` which meand you can never append to it again.

Comment: So how to do that @ mpf82

Comment: Instead of $("#datatable").remove(); you should use $("#datatable > tbody > tr").remove(); to remove all previously populated/displayed data rows

Comment: It didn't worked @Shaggy , the problem is that the code after this line is getting hitted only at the 1st time and not after that " response = $.parseJSON(response);"